# API / Method to get location data from GPS device (USG-MR350) within cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using USB GlobalSat(USG-MR350) GPS device. I want to get location data (latitude and longitude) from the device within my mac cocoa application. Can I use an API to communicate to the device if yes, please help me find it! OR if there is a cocoa method I can use to detect the device and get the data... any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read NMEA data from USB GPS device through cocoa application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462538/how-to-read-nmea-data-from-usb-gps-device-through-cocoa-application)

Answer (score 0):

To access GPS data, you should read it from corresponding COM (serial) port, it is returned as raw-text lines with special format (google for NMEA).
There are libraries/examples for Cocoa, which allows access to COM port, like AMSerialPort: http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php