# How to read NMEA data from USB GPS device through cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gps

I am using **USB GlobalSat(USG-MR350)** GPS device. I want to get location data (latitude and longitude) from the device within my mac cocoa application.Tried to run the **AMSerialPort** sample code.It is detecting the usb device but it is giving output in **nonreadable** format.How can this data be converted to readable format.This is a part of the source code:

```
- (void)serialPortReadData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary
{
    // this method is called if data arrives 
    // @"data" is the actual data, @"serialPort" is the sending port
    AMSerialPort *sendPort = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"serialPort"];
    NSData *data = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    if ([data length] > 0) {
        NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        [outputTextView insertText:text];
        [text release];
        // continue listening
        [sendPort readDataInBackground];
    } else { // port closed
        [outputTextView insertText:@"port closed\r"];
    }
    [outputTextView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [outputTextView displayIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: I started a framework for this a looong time ago before I really knew much about what I was doing with Cocoa, but it might be of some use: https://github.com/nall/GarminFramework

Answer (score 0):

I think that Sirf receiver is by default in binary mode, and that you have to put it in [NMEA mode explicitly](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/NMEA%20Reference%20Manual1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the NSData's ability to print itself as bytes via the [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method.

> [outputTextView insertText:[data description]];

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you are checking port settings.

Default settings for **NMEA** over serial port is `speed:4800stopbit:1 parity:none`.

Check it on the device.